# Add WP Gutenberg Widget via JS by button click

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I create some custom WordPress Gutenberg Widgets which should not appear on the website.

One of these Widgets is a list of events.

When a user want to see all the latest events he has to push a button.

After button click, i want to generate the Widget via JavaScript.

Is this possible in WordPress or with Gutenberg?

I would like to avoid inserting the elements and tagging them with `display: none`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please update your question with the code which you are using for the Gutenberg widget.

Comment: I created a list [here](https://codepen.io/weristsam/pen/poQOpOO?editors=1111). Instead of "load content of custom gutenberg widget" i want to add a gutenberg widget